# Error 1004 when I use Range.Cells() to reference a single cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a small macro that inserts a timestamp in a specific column whenever the user modifies a row. First, I have created a Function that returns the index of the column where the timestamps should be inserted. As a second step, I created a Sub-Procedure to monitor changes. As part of the latter, I am setting the target range for the timestamp by using a row index and a column index.

[This is what my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9IKb.png)

[image]

```
Dim Timestamp As Date
Dim TimestampCell As Range
Dim TimestampColumn As String
Dim TimestampRow As String
Dim Column As Integer

Function getTimestampColumn() As Integer
    For Column = 1 To 5
        If Cells(1, Column).value = "Last updated on" Then
            getTimestampColumn = Column
        End If
    Next Column
End Function

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 1 Then
        TimestampColumn = getTimestampColumn()
        TimestampRow = Target.Row
        Timestamp = Now
        Set TimestampCell = Range(Cells(TimestampRow, TimestampColumn))
        TimestampCell = Timestamp
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem: The macro is throwing a Runtime error (1004). It works fine when I am hardcoding the range to a specific cell. So, it seems as if I am using Range(Cells()) in a wrong way. I have read the Help entry for the Cells property and several sites that explain how to use it but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I know there are a lot of questions on how to use Range(Cells()) and Error 1004 but I have not found clues to a solution in any of them (let me know if I have not searched properly).

[This is what the Debugger says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTVvN.png)

[image]

Comment: remove the Range wrapper.  Just use `Set TimestampCell = Cells(TimestampRow, TimestampColumn)`

Comment: Why do you need to use `Range`? The `Cells` function already return a range (containing a single cell)

Comment: Remove the `Range` call: `Set TimestampCell = Cells(TimestampRow, TimestampColumn)`

Comment: Or, keep `Range()`, but use the `Cells()` twice: `Range(Cells(TimestampRow, TimestampColumn),Cells(TimestampRow, TimestampColumn))`.  With `Range()`, you have to use a cell reference (`Range("A1")`, or two `Cells()` which set the start and end of the range. `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,1))`.

Comment: Note that you'll also get an 1004 even with that correction if `getTimestampColumn` doesn't find a match.

Comment: How does that even work? You are repurposing the reserved word [Range.Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198200.aspx) property in your function without declaring it as a **Long** integer. Use `dim col as long` then `For col= 1 To 5` and `getTimestampColumn = col`. Add an `Exit For` to break the loop when it is found. You are effectively rendering the `Option Explicit` useless.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried removing `Range` but I still get the same error. @BruceWayne, same even when I try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped, I had not seen that. I am a still a beginner when it comes to VBA. I changed the code but the error persists.

Comment: Then you need to step through and ensure that both variables are greater than 0 at the time.

Comment: @Jeeped - `Column` is declared as a global integer.  It just hides the `Column` member of the worksheet in that scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row and column vars are strings for some reason. They should be **Long** integer types.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Timestamp As Date
Dim TimestampCell As Range
Dim TimestampColumn As Long    '<~~ Long integer
Dim TimestampRow As Long       '<~~ Long integer
Dim Column As Integer

Function getTimestampColumn() As Integer
    Dim col As Long
    For col = 1 To 5
        If Cells(1, col).Value = "Last updated on" Then
            getTimestampColumn = col
            Exit For
        End If
    Next col
    If col > 5 Then MsgBox "'Last updated on' not found"
End Function

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 1 Then
        TimestampColumn = getTimestampColumn()
        TimestampRow = Target.Row
        Timestamp = Now
        Set TimestampCell = Cells(TimestampRow, TimestampColumn)
        TimestampCell = Timestamp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeeped! That solved the issue (and my headaches of the last hour or two...).

Comment: I had declared these two variables as Strings because at the beginning I tried calling `Range` (without the `Cells` property) and understood that you have to use strings as an argument for `Range`. I simply forgot to update the variable type...

Comment: Yes, you would have to convert the numerical column number to a letter (there are lots of examples on StackOverflow) but using the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) should be easier.